# How do I update from 9.0.10 to 9.1.0?

Tags: composer, upgrading

I have tried to update drupal 9.0.10 to 9.1 with composer but I cannot:

```
composer outdated 'drupal/*' 
 drupal/core             9.0.10 **9.1.0** Drupal is an open source content manage... 
 drupal/core-recommended 9.0.10 **9.1.0** Locked core dependencies; require this ...
```

I have executed  "composer update drupal/core-recommended --with-all-dependencies" and this is the result

```
loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Nothing to modify in lock file
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Nothing to install, update or remove
Package container-interop/container-interop is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use psr/container instead.
Package doctrine/reflection is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use roave/better-reflection instead.
Generating autoload files
```

This is my composer.json

```
{
    "name": "drupal/recommended-project",
    "description": "Project template for Drupal 8 projects with a relocated document root",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "GPL-2.0-or-later",
    "homepage": "https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal",
    "support": {
        "docs": "https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/index.html",
        "chat": "https://www.drupal.org/node/314178"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "composer/installers": "^1.9",
        "drupal/bootstrap": "^3.23",
        "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": "^9",
        "drupal/core-project-message": "^9",
        "drupal/core-recommended": "^9",
        "drupal/metatag": "^1.13",
        "drupal/migrate_plus": "^5.1",
        "drupal/migrate_tools": "^4.5|^5",
        "drupal/migrate_upgrade": "^3.2",
        "drupal/pathauto": "^1.8",
        "drupal/redirect": "^1.6",
        "drush/drush": "^10.3"
    },
    "conflict": {
        "drupal/drupal": "*"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "config": {
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "drupal-scaffold": {
            "locations": {
                "web-root": "web/"
            }
        },
        "installer-paths": {
            "web/core": [
                "type:drupal-core"
            ],
            "web/libraries/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-library"
            ],
            "web/modules/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-module"
            ],
            "web/profiles/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-profile"
            ],
            "web/themes/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-theme"
            ],
            "drush/Commands/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-drush"
            ],
            "web/modules/custom/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-custom-module"
            ],
            "web/themes/custom/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-custom-theme"
            ]
        },
        "drupal-core-project-message": {
            "include-keys": [
                "homepage",
                "support"
            ],
            "post-create-project-cmd-message": [
                "<bg=blue;fg=white>                                                         </>",
                "<bg=blue;fg=white>  Congratulations, you’ve installed the Drupal codebase  </>",
                "<bg=blue;fg=white>  from the drupal/recommended-project template!          </>",
                "<bg=blue;fg=white>                                                         </>",
                "",
                "<bg=yellow;fg=black>Next steps</>:",
                "  * Install the site: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/install",
                "  * Read the user guide: https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/index.html",
                "  * Get support: https://www.drupal.org/support",
                "  * Get involved with the Drupal community:",
                "      https://www.drupal.org/getting-involved",
                "  * Remove the plugin that prints this message:",
                "      composer remove drupal/core-project-message"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have add the composer.json and I have tried to remove  core " composer remove drupal/core"  but  the result is "Removal failed, drupal/core is still present"

Comment: Try `composer update drupal/core 'drupal/core-*' --with-all-dependencies`. See https://www.drupal.org/docs/updating-drupal/updating-drupal-core-via-composer.

Comment: Same result, 

"Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Nothing to modify in lock file
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Nothing to install, update or remove"

Comment: And when you `composer require drupal/core-recommended` you get what?

Comment: I have executed "composer require drupal/core-recommended --with-all-dependencies"  but it installs  9.1.0-alpha1 instead 9.1.0
composer outdated drupal/*
drupal/core             9.1.0-alpha1 9.1.0 Drupal is an open source content ...
drupal/core-recommended 9.1.0-alpha1 9.1.0 Locked core dependencies; require...
If a try again to update it says "Nothing to install, update or remove"

Comment: Ah yeah, can you please thoroughly read through the release notes to https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/releases/9.1.0 and then raise the minimum stability in your composer.json. Alternatively you could also pin core-recommended to 9.1.0 explicitly.

Comment: Thanks, I have changed  the minimum stability and It has worked with "composer require drupal/core-recommended"

Answer (score 4):

With version 9.1.0 ([release notes](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/releases/9.1.0)) Drupal Composer templates no longer use minimum-stability `dev` as in the past this occasionally produced unexpected results, such as upgrading to newer unstable releases. This is what's currently happening to you.

Raised minimum stability will not affect existing projects; this has to be done manually. For production websites `stable` is recommended.

So in you composer.json replace `"minimum-stability": "dev"` with `"minimum-stability": "stable"` and then simply require core again: `composer require drupal/core-recommended`. This will give you the latest stable release.

From then on for updating core simply run `composer update drupal/core 'drupal/core-*' --with-all-dependencies` as recommended under [Updating Drupal core via Composer](https://www.drupal.org/docs/updating-drupal/updating-drupal-core-via-composer#s-update-drupal-core-code).