# How can I have "minimum-stability": "stable" in my composer.json and install alpha version of a contrib module?

Tags: 9, composer

Trying to update Drupal core to 9.4.7 with `composer update "drupal/core-*" --with-all-dependencies`, I got 9.5.0-beta1 version.
Digging a little in Drupal Answers, I found '[Update installs a beta version](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/303211/update-installs-a-beta-version)' and '[How do I update from 9.0.10 to 9.1.0?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/299091/how-do-i-update-from-9-0-10-to-9-1-0)'.
So I changed my composer.json to `"minimum-stability": "stable"`.
But then I had an issue with [Mime Mail](https://www.drupal.org/project/mimemail) contrib module which only version for Drupal 9 is 8.x-1.0-alpha4.

The only solution I found was to

1. remove Mime Mail
2. update Drupal with composer
3. go back to `"minimum-stability": "dev"`
4. install Mime Mail with Composer

I'm pretty sure this is not the best way to do it...
Any advice on how to handle this situation?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering the title:

> How can I have "minimum-stability": "stable" in my composer.json and
> install alpha version of a contrib module?

All you need to do is specify `version@alpha` for that module in `composer.json`.

For example, my `composer.json` has `minimum-stability: "beta"`, but I have the alpha version of the Field Tools module installed as a dev dependency:

```
  "drupal/field_tools": "^1@alpha",
```